# Can you determine how a neural network produces its results?

Tags: neural-networks

I read an article about neural networks that stated you really can't determine how the network produced a given result.

What I mean is that there might be several thousands of factors behind the result and that you can't really isolate them. Could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Artificial Neural Networks are 100% deterministic. The only operations used are multiplication, addition, and some sort of nonlinear function. In fact, the methods used to train them (usually always back propagation) only work because the network can be reversed, and you can see where each contribution to the end result came from.

Comment: Can you extend your points to explain how someone can identify the role of an individual factor on the result? Does your argument imply that that role will always be the same irrespective of the status of the other factors in the NN?

Comment: Using calculus you can put an exact numeric value on how much any one factor affects any other factor. For example, to find out how much the weight "w" affects an activation "a" downstream, you just calculate the derivative of w with respect to a. The role of each factor will always be the same once training is done, because none of the factors that produce an output change except the input into the network (much unlike a biological neural network where the factors are always changing, an artificial network is fixed in place)

Comment: The Eric Wan diagrammatic Jacobian, with a technically insignificant perturbation of the output, when the input is specified, and the NN has been trained allow the determination of contribution by every deterministic factor in the NN, even with some pretty elaborate topologies.  The graph determination is amazingly simpler than chain rule and lots of symbolic manipulation.  Before Wan there were folks who earned their credentials by proving how to train a particular style.  After Wan, it was not such an issue.